# How to fetch data in react hooks dynamic route?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am writing simple blog collection. I have newest react-router and react-redux. I have all blogs in my store. When I navigate to single blog page it works fine at first time, but when I refresh browser or enter dynamic url straight to address bar, component loose data. What kind of hook I should use to fetch data? I have only this in my SingleBlog to fetch data:

```
 const id = useParams().id
 const blog = useSelector(state => state.blogs.find(b => b.id === id))
```

Comment: `useEffect` can help you to fetch data and re-render. awesome explanation here : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks

Comment: But I can not use useSelector from useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the browser, your whole app restarts, that includes your state that holds the data.

If you want to keep the data even after the browser refreshes, you should then save your data in the `localStorage` and modify the code so that it gets the state from the data saved in the `localStorage`.

How you might do that:
**When you fetch the data**

```
...
// Where data is the variable that holds your fetched data
localStorage.setItem('data_array', JSON.stringify(data));
```

**In the blog reducer**

```
...
// Instead of having the initial state as empty array `[]`, you make it equal
// to whichever data is stored in the localStorage. Because if the localStorage
// have no data, it will still return an empty array `[]`
const initialState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data_array'));

export function blogReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type)
  ...
}
```

**In the blog page**

```
...
// You keep blog const as it is since we took care of the localStorage in
// the reducer
const blog = useSelector(state => state.blogs.find(b => b.id === id))
...
```

---

Quick note:
You shouldn't rely on refreshing the browser to fetch a new blog post/data. You could, however, use `setInterval()` to send a fetch request every `x` time to see if there are any new posts/data, Or you could add a refresh button to your app that fires a request to get any new data

Comment: Example of using `localStorage`?

Comment: I updated the answer to incorporate an example on how to implement `localStorage`

Comment: But I can not use useSelector conditionally either.

Comment: Tell you a better solution. Instead of handling the localStorage in the `blog page` we handle it in the `blog reducer` itself. That way you can keep you `blog page` code as-is and there will be no issues with using `useSelector`. I changed the answer to demonstrate it

Comment: If I save blog information to localStorage, I get error: "Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development".